# How to handle specular highlights in chroma key filter?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, fragment-shader

I am working on chroma key (green screen) filter for android using opengl; the only difference is I am trying to replace not only green background but any color passed by user. I have been able to replace the color but the problem is that it also replaces color from object where light intensity is very high.

Can anyone help me to reduce the light glare from texture so that my filter can work as expected?

Or any reference greenscreen filter which works perfectly.

Anything will be welcomed.

[image]

**EDIT** : I have added screenshot to explain the situation, Here I tried to replace red background with these clouds, it worked for all area excluding the one having glare of light in it. I can overcome this by increasing the tolerance value but then that will make it to replace some yellow pixels from the object.

Comment: Could you give a sample unedited image? Also your current composition formula could be useful.

Comment: @ybungalobill please find image in this link http://imgur.com/a/Qj7p2

shader :-

varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;
uniform float thresholdSensitivity;
uniform vec3 colorToReplace;

void main()
{
vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
vec4 background = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

vec3 diff = color.xyz - colorToReplace;

if(dot(diff, diff) < thresholdSensitivity) {
color = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);
}

gl_FragColor = color;
};

Comment: @ybungalobill you may check this link for reference. This will explain what I am doing for android https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsfGzn

Comment: @AdarshSharma: Put stuff like that in your *question*, not a comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok. Now, can you help me?

Comment: @AdarshSharma When I said "stuff like that", I meant the code you wrote in a comment rather than your question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I got it. You don't need to describe it again and again. Are you here just for timepass?

Comment: @AdarshSharma: obviously your calculation checks the RGB color, not the chroma as it should. Try extracting both chromas and comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm wise just matching RGB colors is going to be difficult.

The first thing to note is that in your case you are really just looking at some form of luminance-sensitive value, not a pure chroma value. Bright pixels will always have a strong response in R, G, and B channels, so simple thresholding isn't going to give a reliable workarond here.

If you extracted a luminance-independent chroma value (like a YUV encoding would do) then you could isolate "redness", "greenness", and "blueness" independent of the brightness of the color.

However, this is still going to have edge cases. For example, what happens if your bottle is red, or has a red label? To solve this you need some form of geometry feature extraction (e.g. sorbel edge detect over the image), and then color replace only within a specific identified region.

None of this is trivial - accurate object detection and recognition is very hard and still very much under active research (e.g. think Tesla cruise control trying to spot and avoid objects while driving).